# Is it possible uploading videos to youtube using jquery?

Tags: jquery, video, using, uploading

I am new to jquery and asp.net,c# mvc technology. I am building a site in which I have to upload videos to the you tube. Can any one help me in giving a sample code for uploading the video from client browser using jquery or asp.net.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a POST request to `http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<youtube_username>/uploads`. You also need to provide an authenticity token.

Check out the [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Direct_uploading) for further information. If you are not sure how to send the request via jQuery also take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).